# Mpv cannot find fftw library

Tags: apt, shared-library, mpv-media-player

When I try to run `mpv` to watch a youtube video, e.g.:

```
mpv [url]
```

it gives the error:

```
mpv: error while loading shared libraries: libfftw3.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed FFTW3 from source for my study some months previously, as I didn't know there was an `apt` package for it. Maybe that has something to do with it.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can try uninstalling FFTW3 the same way you installed it and then install it using `apt`. You can also try symlinking `libfftw3.so` from the directory it is currently installed to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3`.

Comment: `sudo apt install libfftw3-double3` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libfftw3.so.3

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Comment: What exactly worked?